# How to use XmlSlurper in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the below groovy script which I run in groovyconsole and it runs just fine. I'm finding the number of child nodes for a particular node in my xml response and printing out required values for each child node.

```
def path = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('C://SoapUI//ResponseXML/Response.xml'))
NumberOfPositions =  path.Body.GetPositionsAggregateResponse.GetPositionsAggregateResult.AccountPositions.Securities.Positions.children().size()
for(def i=0; i<NumberOfPositions; i++){
println i

println  path.Body.GetPositionsAggregateResponse.GetPositionsAggregateResult.AccountPositions.Securities.Positions.PositionSummary[i].Legs[0].PositionAggregate[0].PositionID[0].text()
println  path.Body.GetPositionsAggregateResponse.GetPositionsAggregateResult.AccountPositions.Securities.Positions.PositionSummary[i].Legs[0].PositionAggregate[0].AccountID[0].text()

}
```

I want to perform the same task in soapUI, but couldn't get it working using groovyutils as mentioned here : http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html

1) How do I parse the xml response from my request to xmlSlurper?
def path = new XmlSlurper().parse (?)

2) Would I be able to use the same code above in soapUI too?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(1)
For parsing the response message you could try the following:

```
def response = context.expand( '${TestRequest#Response}' )
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
```

`TestRequest` represents the name of your test step which is sending the SOAP request message.

(2)
Yes, soapUI should be able to handle any Groovy code.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use normal groovy script in SoapUI. Check this [link](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/01/11/groovy_xml_part_two/), it might help you. But, remember that instead of "println' You need to use "log.info" while scripting in SoapUI.